# jBoss runs fine with the port not present in standalone.xml file

Tags: jboss

I can access JBoss 7.1.1 using the URL : `http://localhost:9990` and it takes me to the management console window.However, one thing strange I noticed is in the `standalone.xml` file. As you can see, there is no **9990** port mentioned anywhere inthe XML code below. Here is the excerpt from the file:

```
<socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9090}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
        <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
```

Could anyone tell me why I can still access the jboss with 9990 port and not with 9090 or any other despite the fact that it's not mentioned anywhere in the XML file?

I have jBoss 7.1.1 version installed on Windows 7.

Comment: Perhaps you are using a different configuration (standalone-full.xml, standalone-full-ha.xml, etc) or forgot restart the server after change config.

Comment: I didn't actually make any changes in that file as far as I remember right from the start and it still runs only on port 9990. Is there any other place I need to check what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess that the value of the 'jboss.management.http.port' property is set somewhere else, either in the start-script you use or standalone.conf. Take a look at the full command line of the server if the value might be set there (-Djboss.management.http.port)

The server.log should output some information on what ports the management interface is binding to, and I believe boot.log might contain the values of some runtime properties.

According to the [documentation for 7.1](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Management+Clients) the default port is 9990 so not sure where 9090 is coming from, might be something left over from AS6, where I believe it was the default?